# Calling a function in child with a ref in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to React Native, coming from React and other front-end tech. I have this `toggle` method in my child component which I would like to call from my parent. Something I tried was using refs. I was familiar with it from React but it isn't working the same, using the following code:

```
gameRef = createRef();

toggleGameMenu = () => {
    this.gameRef.toggle();
}

...

<Sheet title="How would you like to play" ref={this.gameRef} />
```

This will return something like `this.gameRef.toggle isn't a function`. I was prett y sure that the method did exist in my child component. So I was searching for refs in react native and I came across [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html). I thought this was helpfull but I am not sure if I can call the method in my child from my parent? I saw the `setNativeProps` thing but from what I can understand is that it's about properties/values and not calling methods. Anyone with an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Please do not take this in the wrong way, but this totally looks like an x/y problem to me... In React whenever I see a parent component trying to imperatively "poke" one of its descendants, I immediately know that something's wrong and that it should be a better way to solve the problem. So, if you don't mind: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You might want to add how you have defined the child's toggle function.

Answer (score 1):

remove `createRef()`,

instead use this,

```
<Sheet title="How would you like to play" ref={ instance => this.gameRef = instance } />
```

and make sure you use `this.gameRef.toggle()` after component is mounted. before that it will throw error.